# Flutter-Firebase RTDB : Is Push ID mandatory for reading data from Firebase Realtime database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

My current experiment:

1. I want user to sign in and enter details
2. When next time he signs in, i want to retrieve his saved information

My intended database structure:

-"users

------"uid"

-----------firstName

-----------lastName`

I use the below code in flutter to create records:

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword( email: email, password: 
password).then((value)
{
 if(value.user.uid != null ) 
{
   final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users');
   dbRef.push().child(user.uid.toString()).set(User().toJson());
 }
}
```

the data gets created with a push key/ID inbetween:

```
-users
------MFvvXpeRmoQvXkd5VS8 `<---Push ID generated by Firebase`
--------------k8IL4xLQKRf82dxlXNLSHEt2
-----------------------firstName: "sadsadda"
------------------------lastName: "asdsadsad"`
```

Based on documentations, When i try to retrieve the data using the following code:

```
final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users').child(user.uid.toString());

dbRef.equalTo(user.uid.toString()).once().then((snapshot) 
{
  /*snapshot has value null
}
);


//I even added listener<br>
dbRef.onChildAdded.listen((event) {
   readUserInfo(event.snapshot); // even here snapshot value is null.
});
```

Just for testing purpose, i tried to pass the push key in-between by hardcoding,

```
final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users').child('- 
MFvvXpeRmoQvXkd5VS8').child(user.uid.toString());`
```

then "onChildAdded" listener was able to pickup the child entries.
Is this the expected behaviour ?  or is there a way to avoid this randomly generated push id?

Thanks for your time in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to replace the database structure with the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write the user data under their UID, don't call `push()`, but simply do:

```
dbRef.child(user.uid.toString()).set(User().toJson());
```

To then read the data for the user back, use:

```
final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users').child(user.uid.toString());
dbRef.onValue.listen((event) {
   readUserInfo(event.snapshot);
});
```

The `.childAdded` is needed when you want to read a list of child nodes, for example to read all users:

```
final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users');
dbRef.onChildAdded.listen((event) {
   readUserInfo(event.snapshot);
});
```